# C# combobox does not display correctly inside splitcontainer

Tags: c#, combobox, flat

I have a form with a splitcontainer. One of the panels in the splitcontainer then loads a user control. This user control contains a combobox with the following properties changed from default:

1. `DrowdownStyle=DrowDownList`
2. `FlatSyle=flat`
3. `Anchor=top,left,right`

When the form and user control load, the combobox looks as expected:

However, if I resize the splitcontrol, it starts looking weird. If I increase the size of the panel that holds the control, this happens:

[image]

If i decrease the size of the splitter, it looks less weird, but still not how it is supposed to:

[image]

In either case, the combobox starts looking normal once I mouse over it.

Here is my code:

Main Form:

```
//Main form. Has a split container created from the toolbox
public partial class SampleForm:Form
{
    public SampleForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        SampleControl cntrl = new SampleControl();
        splitContainer1.Panel1.Controls.Add(cntrl);
        splitContainer1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
        cntrl.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    }
}
```

User Control:

```
//User control. Has a combobox created from toolbox. Options as described    above
public partial class SampleControl : UserControl
{
    public SampleControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

May be try to set dock to None . Also try to fix the margin for control

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but was having the same problem and just in case someone finds themselves in the same predicament, answer below. Basically, create a new Class:

```vb
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Public Class MyComboBox
    Inherits ComboBox

    Protected Overrides Sub OnResize(e As EventArgs)
        Me.Refresh()
    End Sub

End Class
```

You can either drag this from your toolbox or add it in code. It will then auto redraw itself on resize of any parent controls.

Winforms is a bit like a sibling - flawed and deeply annoying sometimes - but you just gotta love it.